# Как при рантайме создавать новые объекты в функциях не используя массив?

Tags: c++, функции, объекты, односвязный-список, область-видимости

Извиняюсь за возможно тупой вопрос. Но вот как работает моя логика. Добавление нового объекта с помощью массива(упрощенно):

```
    class MyClass
    {
       int data;
     public:
       MyClass()
       ~MyClass()

       MyClass* operator = (MyClass &other)
       {
         this->data = other.data;
         return this;
       }
       void setData()
       {
         cout << "Введите новые данные \n";
         cin >> data;
       }   
    }
    addObject(&Array, &size);

     int main()
     {
     int size = 0;
     MyClass* Array = new MyClass*[size]
     addObject(Array, size);
     delete[] Array;
     return 0;
     }

     addObject(&Array, &size)
     {
        newSize = size + 1;
        MyClass* TempArray = new MyClass*[newSize];
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
           TempArray[i] = Array[i];
        }
        MyClass Object;
        Object.setData();
        TempArray[newSize - 1] = Object;
        delete[] Array;
        Array = TempArray;
     }
```

Если я правильно понимаю массив при выделении ему памяти автоматически создает объекты вызывая конструктор класса. Массив передается по ссылке, а потому он будет доступен на протяжение всего рантайма.  Вот что мне не понятно. Если я хочу сделать так(упрощенно):

```
    class MyClass
    {
       int data;
       MyClass* next;
     public:
       MyClass()
       ~MyClass()
       void setData()
       {
          cout << "Введите новые данные \n";
          cin >> data;
       }
       Object.setNext(*tempObject)
       {
          this->next = &tempObject;
       }

    }
    addObject(&Object);

     int main()
     {
     MyClass Object1;
     addObject(Object1);
     return 0;
     }

     addObject(&Object)
     {
        MyClass tempObject;
        tempObject.setData();
        Object.setNext(&tempObject);
     }
```

Получается поле "next" объекта Object1 содержит указатель на объект tempObject. Но ведь объект tempObject выйдя за пределы видимости функции addObject() должен уничтожится конструктором класса. Так? А значит поле "next" будет указывать уже на некорректные данные. Я понимаю из чего состоит связный список head и т. д. Информации везде полно. Я не могу понять как работать со связным списком. Как передавать его из функции в функцию. Как совладать с областью видимости?

У меня в программе сложная структура разномастных меню, навигация по ним устроена рекурсивно и мне нужно передавать большой объем данных в десятки разных функций. Сейчас данные хранятся в векторах, но в будущем объектов будет больше десятка тысяч а может и сотни. Переназначать каждый раз память для массива такого объема это как-то не эстетично) Вектор же массив по сути? И хотелось бы обойтись без стандартных библиотек.

Comment: А вы сами объекты то же создавайте с помощью new, что бы они не выходили за область видимости. `MyClass *tempObject=new MyClass; ...`

Comment: Спасибо. Я так понял область видимости как-то связана с работой стека? Также я видимо плохо понимал как работает "new". Еще гугля вопрос "как создавать новые переменные во время работы программы" натыкался на ответы "никак, только через массив", думал в массивах есть что-то особенное)) Это меня и запутало. Вы мне своим ответом очень многое разъяснили)) Спасибо еще раз)

Comment: да, со стеком очень даже связано. локальные переменные размещаются в стеке, при входе в функцию первые инструкции резервируют место под все переменные, при выходе восстанавливают указатель стека на момент входа. new (так же как и malloc(), но еще и констракторы классов вызывает) выделяют место в куче, а не в стеке. Но надо внимательно следить за тем, что бы удалять delete все не нужные объекты, созданные new. Иначе у приложения начинается утечка памяти, кроме вас никто память в куче не освободит

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное. Теперь я окончательно все понял. Объекты создает не массив (думал он определяет структуру хранящихся в нем объектов), а оператор "new", и он не только выделяет память а еще и структурирует ее под все переменные класса. И с выделенным им участком памяти уже можно работать как с полноценным объектом. А область видимости придумана не для того чтобы мешать мне кодить, а обусловлена вполне понятными причинами))